# Unity move of child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a small demo where objects shall move based on the eyetracker data from a FOVE VR headset.

When I try to move my two objects around ("Gaze Responder - Target" and "Gaze Responder - Fixation"): They don't move, and the colliders stop working.

I have the following hierarchy in Unity3d (2017.4.40f1)

[image: Hierarchy in Unity3d]

The following Code is attached to GazeContingenVisualField

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VisualField_test : FOVEBehavior
{
    private GameObject Target;
    private GameObject Fixation;

    private GameObject TargetGazeObj;
    private GameObject FixationGazeObj;

    private Collider collider_Fixation;
    private Collider collider_Target;

    private float TimeShowFix;

    private float T_ShowStim = 5.1f;
    private float T_TimeOut = 10.0f;

    private float[] StimPos_H_deg = { 0, 0, 0, 10, -10, 10, 10, -10, -10 };
    private float[] StimPos_V_deg = { 0, 10, -10, 0, 0, 10, -10, 10, -10 };
    private float[] StimPos_H = new float[100];
    private float[] StimPos_V = new float[100];


    private Material materialTarget;
    private Material materialFixaton;

    public enum StateTypes { WaitStart, TargetOn, TargetTimeOut, TargetSeen };
    public StateTypes CurrentState = StateTypes.WaitStart;
    public int idx_stimpos = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < StimPos_H_deg.Length; i++)
        {
            StimPos_H[i] = Mathf.Tan(StimPos_H_deg[i] / 180.0F * Mathf.PI) * 20.0F;
            StimPos_V[i] = Mathf.Tan(StimPos_V_deg[i] / 180.0F * Mathf.PI) * 20.0F;
        }

        Target = transform.Find("Gaze Responder - Target").gameObject;
        Fixation = transform.Find("Gaze Responder - Fixation").gameObject;

        TargetGazeObj = Target.transform.Find("Gazable object").gameObject;
        FixationGazeObj = Fixation.transform.Find("Gazable object").gameObject;

        materialTarget = TargetGazeObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        materialFixaton = FixationGazeObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        collider_Fixation = FixationGazeObj.GetComponent<Collider>();
        collider_Target = TargetGazeObj.GetComponent<Collider>();

        materialTarget.DisableKeyword("_EMISSION");

        materialFixaton.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
        materialFixaton.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.green);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        switch (CurrentState)
        {
            case StateTypes.WaitStart:
                if (FoveInterface.Gazecast(collider_Fixation))
                {
                    CurrentState = StateTypes.TargetOn;
                    TimeShowFix = Time.time;

                    materialFixaton.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
                    materialFixaton.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.white);

                }

                break;
            case StateTypes.TargetOn:
                if (FoveInterface.Gazecast(collider_Target))
                {
                    CurrentState = StateTypes.TargetSeen;
                    materialTarget.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
                    materialTarget.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.yellow);
                }

               else if (Time.time <= TimeShowFix + T_ShowStim)
                {
                    materialTarget.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
                    materialTarget.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.white);
                }
                else
                {
                    materialTarget.DisableKeyword("_EMISSION");
                }

                if (Time.time >= TimeShowFix + T_TimeOut)
                {
                    CurrentState = StateTypes.TargetTimeOut;
                }


                break;
            case StateTypes.TargetTimeOut:
                idx_stimpos = (idx_stimpos +1) % StimPos_H.Length ;
                materialTarget.DisableKeyword("_EMISSION");
                Target.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StimPos_H[idx_stimpos], StimPos_V[idx_stimpos], 0.0f);
                CurrentState = StateTypes.TargetOn;
                TimeShowFix = Time.time;
                break;

            case StateTypes.TargetSeen:
                idx_stimpos = (idx_stimpos + 1) % StimPos_H.Length;
                materialTarget.DisableKeyword("_EMISSION");

                Fixation.transform.localPosition = Target.transform.localPosition;
                Target.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StimPos_H[idx_stimpos], StimPos_V[idx_stimpos], 5.0f);
                CurrentState = StateTypes.TargetOn;
                TimeShowFix = Time.time;

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Fove.Unity;
using UnityEngine;

public class FOVEBehavior: MonoBehaviour
{
    private static FoveInterface foveInterface;
    public static FoveInterface FoveInterface
    {
        get
        {
            if (foveInterface == null)
            {
                // returns the first FoveInterface found here but you should adapt this code to your game
                // especially in the case where you could have no or several FoveInterface in your game
                foveInterface = FindObjectOfType<FoveInterface>();
            }

            return foveInterface;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformation of the object works correctly but the associated lightning was set to static therefore the emissive object seemed to not be changing its position.

The Lightmap Static property of the Mesh Renderer must be disabled

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how FOVE works, but is it somehow resetting the "-Target" objects transform?

When I was working with AR, some GameObjects (the targets) couldn't be moved around because their transforms were handled by the library and trying to do so caused all sorts of weird problems.

Perhaps what you want to move are the actual "Gazable Objects" (I know this is VR, but maybe it's the same issue).

And if anything, on the last case statement you're setting the local position of Fixation to the local position of TargetGazeObj but their coordinate references are probably different, so you may want to utilize the global position there.

Comment: Thanks for your response: 
The library should not reseting the transforms of these objects; edited the question to add the inheritance.  
Last case this is indeed an error introduced while try tring the move the TargetGazeObjects